# OpenOffice Calc - complicated formula for comparison

Tags: excel, excel-formula, openoffice-calc

I have basically 4 lists: for ease, call them SKU-A , Price-A, SKU-B, Price-B

skuA is a list of about 1000 values, skuB being a list of about 20000 values. I need to compare every item in skuA with skuB, and IF skuB has a price that is not 9876.54, then to use the skuB price, otherwise using the skuA price, or if no price is listed, 9876.54.

I know quite a bit on formulas, but comparing the 2 seperate lists is completely messing me up, for the life of me I cannot get a vlookup or something working right; any advice?

both sku lists are unordered, so skuA:300 may not be skuB:300, it could be skuB:10, skuB:9850, or anywhere in between

if easier, I can do it in excel as well.

Comment: 9876.54 is a "magic number" to indicate a flag?  If this is the case, is there a way to fix that?  That's a bit of a maintenance nightmare if that's the case.

Comment: yes, 9876.54 is actually a coded piece that isn't really adjustable, when the price is that, we have javascript on our site that changes a bunch of stuff. realistically, that number can change, but because of our price % breakpoints and the way quantities work, it is basically impossible to get that number "on accident"

Comment: Right. It's a risk-reward thing. As soon as your "price" means something else besides "price" based on its value, you introduce the risk that 9876.54 will be a legitimate price in the future. If your flag is stored separately, then your price is always actually a price.

Comment: possibly, we just have been careful to ensure that nothing gets priced that - in a store with about 20,000 items, and that flag happening on easily 75%+ of them, its the "simple" method - I would love to do it via a smarter way, but alas, our platform doesn't support php or anything really, only javascript >< - bosses choice -- Either way, this is rapidly getting off-topic, so I shall rephrase the question to state that ignoring the 9876.54 as a potential problem and stating I understand the inherent flaws within that design :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work (Excel 2007 or later only):

[image: multiple rules]

Formula in **Use This Price** (`F2`) is

`=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A2,H:I,2,FALSE)=9876.54,B2,VLOOKUP(A2,H:I,2,FALSE)),9876.54)`

temp1, temp2 and temp3 are not necessary but in the spirit of "showing my work" I left them in so you can see how I got to the solution.

`temp1=VLOOKUP(A2,H:I,2,FALSE)`

`temp2=IF(C2=9876.54,B2,C2)`

`temp3=IFERROR(D2,9876.54)`

Comment: thanks, I actually found out earlier this morning that the entire concept wouldn't work as there was another variable mixed in that would prohibit it, but thanks a ton for the help, as I am sure this will come up in the future!